# Replace numbers beyond a limit with NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

```
time                 c1        c2
1 2017-07-23 11:39:10  3.385661  3.193302
2 2017-07-23 11:39:20  3.157000  2.912690
3 2017-07-23 11:39:30  3.277145  3.124290
4 2017-07-23 11:39:40  3.126075  2.982679
5 2017-07-23 11:39:50  3.135766  2.985840
6 2017-07-23 11:40:00  3.166134  3.016147
7 2017-07-23 11:40:10  2.487507  2.256214
8 2017-07-23 11:40:20  3.348368  3.158728
9 2017-07-23 11:40:30  3.219001  2.996357
10 2017-07-23 11:40:40  2.862558  2.711170
11 2017-07-23 11:40:50  2.558438  2.346303
12 2017-07-23 11:41:00  3.338989  3.192018
13 2017-07-23 11:41:10  2.674149  2.496557
14 2017-07-23 11:41:20  3.523231  3.315889
15 2017-07-23 11:41:30  2.931527  2.740840
16 2017-07-23 11:41:40  3.078464  2.938004
```

I have a dataframe like below. How do i replace all values greater or smaller than a specific num with NAN except time column. Please suggest.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['time'])
df[df[cols].values < 3.523231)] = np.nan
```

It doesn't work.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say for example, you're trying to filter out values under `3`. You can use `boolean indexing`:

```
In [835]: df[cols] = df[cols][df[cols] >= 3]; df[cols].head()
Out[835]: 
         c1        c2
0  3.157000       NaN
1  3.277145  3.124290
2  3.126075       NaN
3  3.135766       NaN
4  3.166134  3.016147
```

You can also use `df.applymap`:

```
In [836]: df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x < 3 else x); df[cols].head()
Out[836]: 
         c1        c2
0  3.157000       NaN
1  3.277145  3.124290
2  3.126075       NaN
3  3.135766       NaN
4  3.166134  3.016147
```

Comment: Can you check my answer? I mean just to check if that is also fine or not?

Comment: @Ashag If it gives the right output, it seems fine. I think Boolean indexing would be faster though.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[cols] = df[cols].mask((df[cols].values < float(to_exclude)), np.nan)
df[cols] = df[cols].mask((df[cols].values > float(to_exclude)), np.nan)
```